# How can I set sensitivity for my gps tracker?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

Could you please help me? I have a task to make a GPS tracker that would pass GPS data to Firebase. But the key point is that the tracker should have the following sensitivity - 60 meters (10 for test build), period every 10 minutes (5 seconds for test build).

As I understood it should track each 10 min only if you pass 60 meters. So if I passed 40 meters it shouldn't track it.

In the Usecase I wrote the following method with interval, smallestDisplacement but it doesn't work as I expected. Could you please help me with it?

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun saveLocation() {
    val locationRequest = LocationRequest().apply {
        interval = com.example.gpstracker.BuildConfig.TRACKING_INTERVAL_MILLIS
        fastestInterval = com.example.gpstracker.BuildConfig.TRACKING_INTERVAL_MILLIS
        smallestDisplacement = com.example.gpstracker.BuildConfig.TRACKING_INTERVAL_METERS.toFloat()
    }

    val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult.locations.let { locations ->
                val location = locations.last()
                saveLocationToFirebase(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            }
        }
    }
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.myLooper()
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: We see no 60 meters or 10 minutes in your code.

Comment: It's set in BuildConfig. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Dont do so complicated. Just write interval = 10; Much easier to follow your problem

Answer (score 0):

Both of the parameters you are setting are minimums, so you will get a locationCallBack when either the minimum time or the minimum distance are passed.

I suggest that you just set the minimum time and every 10 minutes you will get a locationCallBack, where you can deal with the distance threshold yourself.

calculate the distance between this location and last location
( In Kotlin I would use distance = lastLocation.distanceTo(location) )
if it is greater than your threshold then
process it
set last location = this location for next time
(In Kotlin this would be lastLocation.set(location) )
else
do nothing